# CDbCommand не удалось исполнить SQL-запрос: CDbCommand не удалось подготовить SQL-запрос: SQLSTATE[HY000]

Tags: php, база-данных, yii2, letsencrypt

после установки ssl сертификата letsencrypt на сайт в панели управления ispManager, OS Debian 7, сайт не загружается.. Вместо сайта отображается:

```
CDbCommand не удалось исполнить SQL-запрос: CDbCommand не удалось подготовить SQL-запрос: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 table YiiCache already exists. The SQL statement executed was: CREATE TABLE YiiCache
(
id CHAR(128) PRIMARY KEY,
expire INTEGER,
value BLOB
)
```

В чём может быть проблема? Я ведь ничего в коде не трогала

Comment: Причем тут сертификат? Ошибка в том, что Ваш "сайт" пытается создать таблицу которая уже существует.

Comment: @robertobadjo До того как я установила сертификат сайт работал корректно.. Но именно после добавления сертификата, вышла такая ошибка.. Почему интересно он пытается создать некую таблицу?

Comment: Удалите таблицу в БД `YiiCache`, должно помочь на первое время

Comment: @robertobadjo  Спасибо сейчас попробую